# using bind(this) and passing an argument together

Tags: javascript, object, this

I would like to understand how to use bind(this) in this specific case:

```
this.resizeImages(maxcat, this); //this belongs to the Widget Object

Widget.prototype.resizeImages = function(maxcat, self)
{
    switch(maxcat)
    {
        case "firstcase":
            self.piePaper.path(activityImages[maxcat]);
        break;            
    }
}
```

instead of using two arguments, how do I use bind(this) and pass the argument maxcat together?

I would like to have a method like this:

```
Widget.prototype.resizeImages = function(maxcat)
{
    switch(maxcat)
    {
        case "firstcase":
            this.piePaper.path(activityImages[maxcat]); //this belongs to the Widget Object
        break;            
    }
}
```

I would like to have something like: `this.resizeImages(maxcat).bind(this);` that of course it doesn't work, it's just to give an example.

Comment: Why not simply `this.resizeImages(maxcat);` as `this` is the widget object itself

Comment: that can be an option as well, it's only a style related question, to learn an additional option ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this out (I know it's been almost 2 years, but answering anyways):

```
  this.resizeImages.bind(this, maxcat)();
```